# Is it possible to create self hosted integration runtime using VMSS?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need this kind of setup as it will save money as many window virtual machines are needed, such as one for Datagateway, SHIR for Datafactory, and SHIR for Purview, and which will only start up when there is a call, for example very similar to the azure devops agent on VMSS which used to only start instances under VMSS when there is job requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this is no. See here for example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1010423/can-we-install-shir-on-virtual-mahine-scale-set-is?orderby=oldest

However, you can think about basing your SHIR in containers or even app service:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-run-self-hosted-integration-runtime-in-windows-container